# How to get the value of a form field in capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, ruby-on-rails-7

Is there a way to get the value of a form field out of Capybara?

I know I can check that a form field is pre-filled correctly in Minitest by using:

`assert page.has_field? "some_field", with: "some_value"`

But is there a way to get the form field value, the way capybara reads it? The reason I ask is that I am trying to get capybara to test whether a datetime_field is prefilled correctly, and I'm having a heck of a time getting the strftime format correct. If I could get the value that capybara is checking against out even once using debugger or puts, then it would be trivial to design the `with: "some_value"` correctly.

**--EDIT--**
Ok, contrary to my comment, I am still struggling with this. I got it working on one part of a form by matching the format of the `value=""` attribute in the html tag.

But now I am dealing with another part of the form where a default value is filled in based on a turbo frame refresh using a value that's inputted earlier.

When I try `save_page` in Capybara, the html source contains this:

```
<input class="form-control" value="2024-02-07T00:17:00" type="datetime-local" name="record[actual_end_datetime]" id="record_actual_end_datetime">
```

But yet this Minitest assertion fails:

```
puts the_time = p_e_time.in_time_zone.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00")
assert page.has_field? "record[actual_end_datetime]", with: the_time
```

Even though the puts output matches the exact string that is seen in the html: 2024-02-07T00:17:00. The test passes if I comment out the 'with:', so I'm really struggling to see how to get this match to work.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: I was able to match it eventually by matching the value given in the form html (which is different from how the text is displayed in the datetime_field). Still curious if there is a way to extract the value out that capybara is trying to match, as there might be other debugging situations where that would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer about using find_field(...).value is correct, and returns the value property which is different from the value attribute in the HTML since the value property is updated with user edits. That being said you should NEVER be using Capybaras predicates with asset like

```
assert page.has_field? ...
```

By using that you are potentially removing Capybaras retrying behavior (important for async page updates) and losing the detailed error messages which would have likely given you what you wanted in the first place.  Instead you should be using the assertions provided by Capybara and doing

```
assert_field("record[actual_end_datetime]", with: the_time)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I just tried assert_field and you are of course correct that it would've saved me time and frustration right off the top. I need to do a bit more reading  to really understand the nitty gritty details of why the second way works so much better. 

Very high value answer (to me at least). Thank you!

Comment: The reason the second way is better is that the assertion has enough information to display useful error details.  The first approach is only asserting that a function (the `has_field?` predicate) returns true or false, with no other information to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

```
puts find_field("record[actual_end_datetime]").value
```

Outputs exactly what Capybara is trying to match (which doesn't neccesarily equal what is in the `value` field of the html). Solved within seconds once I had this.